# Error while setting up tagging for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, tagging

I'm trying to setup multiple tagging in my app. I have used a single tag and tagging model which works fine for tagging a single model.

However, after setting up the association, i got this error when i wanted to create a new question `undefined method map for nil:NilClass` which actually points to `<%= select_tag(:kategory_id, options_for_select(@kategories), :prompt => "Select Category", class: "form-control") %>`. I don't know why it's pointing to this since it has nothing to do with the tagging. I might have made a mistake somewhere which i could not figure out.

Here is how i do the setup.

I added taggable_id and taggable_type to taggings table.

```
class AddAttributesToTaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :taggings, :taggable_id, :integer
    add_column :taggings, :taggable_type, :string

    add_index :taggings, [:taggable_type, :taggable_id]
  end
end
```

Tag.rb

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :taggings

    has_many :posts, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: Post
    has_many :questions, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: Question

    has_many :user_tags, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :user_tags

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      name_changed?
    end
end
```

tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :kategory

  validates :title, :content, presence: true
  is_impressionable counter_cache: true, unique: :all
  Question.order('impressions_count DESC')
  scope :most_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        title_changed?
    end

  include Taggable

  def related_questions
      Question.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: self.tags.pluck(:id) }).where.not(id: self.id)
  end
end
```

models/concerns/taggable.rb

```
module Taggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  end  

  def tag_list
    self.tags.collect do |tag|
      tag.name
    end.join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(tags_string)
    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
    new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.friendly.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
    self.tags = new_or_found_tags
  end

end
```

tags and taggings table in schema.rb

```
create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "taggable_id"
    t.string "taggable_type"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
    t.index ["taggable_type", "taggable_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_type_and_taggable_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_tags_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

questions/_form

```
<%= form_with(model: question, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <b><%= form.label "Category" %></b>
    <%= select_tag(:kategory_id, options_for_select(@kategories), :prompt => "Select Category", class: "form-control") %>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="field">
    <b><%= form.label :title %></b>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :question_title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, id: :question_content, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :tag_list %>
    <%= form.text_field :tag_list %>
  </div>

    <br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_contacts
  before_action :find_kategory
  impressionist :actions=>[:show,:index]

  # GET /questions
  # GET /questions.json
  def index
    if params[:kategory].blank?
      @questions = Question.most_recent
    else
      @kategory_id = Kategory.find_by(name: params[:kategory]).id
      @questions = Question.where(:kategory_id => @kategory_id).most_recent
    end
  end

  # GET /questions/1
  # GET /questions/1.json
  def show
    impressionist(@question)
    @most_viewed = Question.order('impressions_count DESC').take(20)
  end

  # GET /questions/new
  def new
    @question = current_user.questions.build
    @kategories = Kategory.all.map{ |k| [k.name, k.id] }
  end

  # GET /questions/1/edit
  def edit
    @kategories = Kategory.all.map{ |k| [k.name, k.id] }
  end

  # POST /questions
  # POST /questions.json
  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(question_params)
    @question.kategory_id = params[:kategory_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your question was successfully posted.'
        format.html { redirect_to @question }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Your question was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to @question }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /questions/1
  # DELETE /questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:success] = 'Your question has been deleted.'
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def most_viewed
    @questions = Question.order('impressions_count DESC').take(20)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_question
      @question = Question.friendly.includes(:tags).find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :content, :kategory_id, :tag_list)
    end

    def find_contacts
      @contacts = user_signed_in? ? current_user.all_active_contacts : ''
    end

    def find_kategory
      @questions = Kategory.where(:kategory_id => @kategory_id)
    end
end
```

**UPDATE:**I'm now able to save a question without adding any tag but with tags added, I get a form error that `tagging is invalid`. **Tags are properly loaded when I edit a question.**

Error Log:

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-13 12:01:01 +0100
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"hgLn8bzd6fVSzCIPtRd3P0Jp/LEso
/h5cKNBY0a80x3i4RF6tpLlRyqmls3xRFryqyP1/s/rLDVIt9C1/uK+qw==", "kategory_id"=>"1"
, "question"=>{"title"=>"Help!!! My Dell Inspiron 6400 is hanging", "content"=>"
Lorem ipsum dolor amet seitan offal ethical, beard viral lo-fi put a bird on it
salvia actually yr. Ethical ennui pitchfork fanny pack, gentrify seitan sartoria
l bespoke. Viral 90's church-key swag, you probably haven't heard of them banh m
i intelligentsia brunch DIY iceland wolf pitchfork. Everyday carry photo booth n
ormcore XOXO tumblr portland.\r\n\r\nBrooklyn heirloom kombucha, edison bulb leg
gings hell of DIY chartreuse austin tacos bitters. Blog hexagon copper mug blue
bottle cray. Post-ironic direct trade kale chips mumblecore. Craft beer squid cr
onut vape, hoodie bitters succulents ramps snackwave vegan small batch brunch ch
ia food truck umami. Chillwave blue bottle viral raclette authentic health goth
vape coloring book cardigan 3 wolf moon taxidermy. Gluten-free tote bag hella, l
omo pinterest direct trade gastropub tattooed. Iceland hammock post-ironic, bush
wick cornhole tumeric dreamcatcher blog palo santo chartreuse 90's food truck sy
nth chicharrones.", "tag_list"=>"hardware"}, "commit"=>"Create Question"}
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDE
R BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Private::Conversation Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "private_conversations".* FROM "pri
vate_conversations" WHERE ("private_conversations"."recipient_id" = $1 OR "priva
te_conversations"."sender_id" = $2)  [["recipient_id", 3], ["sender_id", 3]]
  Private::Message Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "private_messages".* FROM "private_messa
ges" WHERE "private_messages"."conversation_id" IN (2, 3, 4, 6)
  Group::Conversation Load (3.9ms)  SELECT "group_conversations".* FROM "group_c
onversations" INNER JOIN "group_conversations_users" ON "group_conversations"."i
d" = "group_conversations_users"."conversation_id" WHERE "group_conversations_us
ers"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
  Group::Message Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "group_messages".* FROM "group_messages" W
HERE "group_messages"."conversation_id" = 1
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (2, 3,
5)
   (40.0ms)  SELECT "group_conversations"."id" FROM "group_conversations" INNER
JOIN "group_conversations_users" ON "group_conversations"."id" = "group_conversa
tions_users"."conversation_id" WHERE "group_conversations_users"."user_id" = $1
 [["user_id", 3]]
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT "group_conversations"."id" FROM "group_conversations" I
NNER JOIN "group_conversations_users" ON "group_conversations"."id" = "group_con
versations_users"."conversation_id" WHERE "group_conversations_users"."user_id"
= $1  [["user_id", 3]]
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "contacts" ON "use
rs"."id" = "contacts"."contact_id" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = $1 AND "contacts
"."accepted" = $2  [["user_id", 3], ["accepted", "t"]]
  User Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "contacts" ON "use
rs"."id" = "contacts"."user_id" WHERE "contacts"."contact_id" = $1 AND "contacts
"."accepted" = $2 ORDER BY "users"."created_at" ASC  [["contact_id", 3], ["accep
ted", "t"]]
  Tag Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT
$2  [["name", "hardware"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Kategory Load (10.7ms)  SELECT "kategories".* FROM "kategories"
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  Question Exists (4.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "questions" WHERE ("questions".
"id" IS NOT NULL) AND "questions"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "help-my-dell-
inspiron-6400-is-hanging"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Kategory Load (5.9ms)  SELECT  "kategories".* FROM "kategories" WHERE "kategor
ies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering questions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered questions/_form.html.erb (17.6ms)
  Rendered questions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (141.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/_toggle_button.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/_home_button.html.erb (30.3ms)
  User Load (28.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIM
IT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/conversations/_private.html.erb (
73.2ms)
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMI
T $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $
1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/conversations/_private.html.erb (
109.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/conversations/_group.html.erb (3.
9ms)
  User Load (30.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIM
IT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/conversations/_private.html.erb (
40.0ms)
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $
1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMI
T $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/conversations/_private.html.erb (
100.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/_conversations.html.erb (983.4ms)

  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "contacts" ON "use
rs"."id" = "contacts"."user_id" WHERE "contacts"."contact_id" = $1 AND "contacts
"."accepted" = $2  [["contact_id", 3], ["accepted", "f"]]
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/contact_requests/_no_requests.htm
l.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/dropdowns/_contact_requests.html.erb (374.0
ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/header/_dropdowns.html.erb (1713.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/_header.html.erb (2485.4ms)
  Kategory Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "kategories".* FROM "kategories"
  Rendered layouts/navigation/collapsible_elements/_constant_links.html.erb (2.0
ms)
   (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "save_questions" ON "que
stions"."id" = "save_questions"."question_id" WHERE "save_questions"."user_id" =
 $1  [["user_id", 3]]
  Rendered layouts/navigation/collapsible_elements/_signed_in_links.html.erb (21
.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/_collapsible_elements.html.erb (543.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (3323.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/application/_private_conversations_windows.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/application/_group_conversations_windows.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22203ms (Views: 21796.6ms | ActiveRecord: 158.2ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `@kategories = Kategory.all.map{ |k| [k.name, k.id] }` in create and update actions. This actions rerender new/edit actions if they can't save the question, and they need @kategories for rerendering

If you provide the full server log for create action I can try to help you to figure out - why @question can not be saved

Comment: After adding `@kategories = Kategory.all.map{ |k| [k.name, k.id] }` to create action it somehow worked but display a form error `Taggings is invalid` which actually should have been in this topic if I had discovered it before. I entered tags like `lifestyle, choice`. Tags code is pasted in the question.

Comment: @Lashe, I think there is some problem in your `tag_list=(tags_string)` method, but I need the **full** server log to find the issue

Comment: Oh... Full server log? From development.log?

Comment: @Lashe, no :) Log for create action, when you have an error about taggings

Comment: I've added the log as part of the question.

Comment: @Lashe, and where is the error in the log? Log should start from 'Processing by QuestionsController#action_name as HTML', contain the error (if you still have it) and finish with 'Completed status_code in some_number ms (Views: some_number ms | ActiveRecord: some_number ms)'

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your `@kategories`, or something within there (perhaps a `name`), is nil, hence the error :) (Hopefully this is a good thing, as all may be well with your tagging.)

Ensure `Kategory.all.map { |k| [k.name, k.id] }` in your `new` action is returning records and this error should go away.

N.B. you can also use [`options_from_collection_for_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) here.

```
# in the controller
def new
  @question = current_user.questions.build
  @kategories = Kategory.all
end

# and the view
<%= select_tag(:kategory_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@kategories, :name, :id), prompt: "Select Category", class: "form-control") %>
```

This way, if you don't have any categories, you won't get an error - instead, you just won't have any options available.

Comment: I have this in my questions_controller now
 
`def new
    @question = current_user.questions.build
    @kategories = Kategory.all
    @kategories = Kategory.all.map{ |k| [k.name, k.id] }
  end`

I still see the same error.

Comment: The problem is `Kategory.all` doesn't seem to be returning any records. Have you confirmed this in the console? Updating your code as in the comment won't do anything: `@kategories` gets overwritten by the same code as your existing project. I've updated my answer to remove the `...` that seems to have cause confusion here.

Comment: Everything was working well before I started the tagging thing.

Comment: That's not to say this isn't the cause - might be the `Kategory` model got wiped at some point. Either way, some data is missing somewhere in there. Have you tried my updated code, including `options_from_collection_for_select` in the view?

Comment: If you look at the source of [`options_for_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select), it calls `map` a couple of times. Therefore, if you're feeding it bad / missing data (e.g. `name` is `nil`), you'll get the error you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, I have tried your updated code... `NoMethodError - undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap:
  app/views/questions/_form.html.erb:16:in `block in _app_views_questions__form_
html_erb___939972431_105699312'
  app/views/questions/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_questions__form_html_erb__
_939972431_105699312'
  app/views/questions/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_questions_new_html_erb___153
577014_106108056'
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:42:in `create'`